# ASP.Net AJAX calendar - only allow the user to select Mondays

Tags: asp.net, ajax, select, calendar, dayofweek

I have a ASP.NET AJAX Calender and a TextBox. I want the user should be able to select only Mondays from the calender as that is the business rule.

I can achieve this by using regular ASP.NET calendar control using the DayRender event, however I wish to use the AJAX Calender control because of its better appearance, easy navigation and partial postback.

How can I achieve this (selecting only Mondays) using ASP.NET AJAX calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could only workaround by `alert` the user if he tries to select anything else than a Monday:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkDate(sender,args){
       if (sender._selectedDate.getDay() != 1){
           alert("You can only select Mondays!");
           sender._selectedDate = new Date(); //set back to current date
           sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
       }
    }
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
   OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
```

Comment: Tim thanks for the answer, absolutely your code makes sense for me, it should work but when I used in my app it is not working, the javascript function is not being called.Here is the Code Below :     <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkDate(sender, args) {

            if (sender._selectedDate.getDay() % 1 != 0) {
                alert("You can only select Mondays!");
                sender._selectedDate = new Date(); //set back to current date         sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
            }
        }
</script>

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="txtStartDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>

Comment: Tim it worked : --  I modified a bit of the JavaScript function  from .getDay() % 1 != 0  TO   .getDay() != 1 IT WORKED NOW...!! Thanks for pointing me to the correct direction..!!

Comment: @msbyuva: sorry that i haven't time enough to test it, but i hoped that you get it working. I will correct it later. Glad i could help.

Comment: Yeah it worked after making a small change, Thank You so much for pointing me to correct direction..!!!

Comment: @msbyuva, You should mark this answer as "Correct" if it has solved your problems.

Comment: @Graham actually it took me to the correct direction, after making a small modification to it it worked..!! I said the same to @TIM who actually responded..!! He said he will edit /update it, so was waiting him to make that.

Comment: @msbyuva: i've corrected my answer already [40 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6550393/revisions). Thanks for accepting.

Comment: @TIM, oops sorry.. have not seen in rush of long weekend mood..!! Thanks again sir..!!!