# Disable dates conditionally with Asp.net Ajax Calendar Extender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms, calendarextender

If you have used [Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx), i am looking for ways to disable dates based on selection from another calendar selected date. In a project management application there are end and start dates, i am looking for ways to validate these on client. Someways would require postback which i am not willing to perform. There seems to be StartDate and EndDate properties for the calendar on the server, but does not seem to have any client side counterparts. Have you got any ideas how i can perform this.

Comment: There is no way to disable dates in a CalendarExtender. You should use a RangeValidator to validate the selected date on client(and server)side. Additionally you could use javascript and handle the `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550393/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter but sure there must be some client function that disables the dates,example link i provided in question shows one. But sadly i work on `Asp.net 2.0` so no `StartDate` and `EndDate` properties for my version. Least i can i validate with custom validator on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite _cell_onclick javascript event to show an alert if a wrong date is chosen depending on the selected date in the other calendar.

Here is an example: [Ajaxtoolkit Calendar Extender close button and date restriction](http://www.karpach.com/ajaxtoolkit-calendar-extender-tweaks.htm)