# Ajax Calendar Extender Disable Specific Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net

Example :
Start Date : 4/08/12
End Date : 4/12/12
Submit button

I want to disable all dates from 4/0812 to 4/12/12 when Submit Button is clicked. I'm using asp.net c#
and also when my Page is loaded and when the CalendarExtender is appearing again it the 4/08/12 to 4/12/12 can't be selected (disabled).

Example
Database
Dates
4/08/12
4/09/12
4/10/12
4/11/12
4/12/12

Those dates should be disabled.

I hope anyone can help me :| i'm new in using calendarExtender.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at a previous answer of me on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608062/how-to-disable-previous-dates-in-calendarextender-control-through-its-render-eve/5608560#5608560

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [Disable dates conditionally with Asp.net Ajax Calendar Extender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711096/disable-dates-conditionally-with-asp-net-ajax-calendar-extender)

The other way to try to do this and its only an idea is to return a false on button click. In addition, you'll have to try to apply css to the ones you want disabled (to make them look disabled/grayed out) for which you'll have to dig down to see which styles you need to apply to which elements. And an obvious thing to remember is that you can't just rely only on client side validation because javascript could be disabled. So please make sure to add validations on server side as well.

Comment: how should i pass the disable dates to the javascript? :| i can't understand but thanks for the reply to my question

Comment: You can write them to a hidden textbox with delimited values from server side, which you then use on the client side.

Comment: how should i do that? can you post some example codes? :| thanks